# Optimizing loop. Faster ResultList.append( [ c, d, c[1]/d[1]] )? Array? Map?

Tags: python

The following works well but I'd like to make it faster.  The actual application could process Tuple1 and Tuple2 each with 30,000 elements and 17 nested sequences per element.  I see numerous questions about faster loops and have tried an array and map without improvement.

```
for i in Tuple1:
 print i

((1, 2.2, 3), (2, 3.3, 4))
((5, 6.6, 7), (6, 7.7, 8))

for i in Tuple2:
 print i

((10, 11, 12), (11, 12, 13), (12, 13, 14))
((20, 21, 22), (21, 22, 23), (22, 23, 24))

ResultList = []

for a in Tuple1:
 for b in Tuple2:
  for c in a:
   for d in b:
    ResultList.append( [c, d, c[1]/d[1]] )
  SomeFunction() # Processes ResultList and is not a concern.
  ResultList=[]
```

An example of a ResultList processed by SomeFunction.

```
[(1, 2.2, 3), (10, 11, 12), 0.2]
[(1, 2.2, 3), (11, 12, 13), 0.18333333333333335]
[(1, 2.2, 3), (12, 13, 14), 0.16923076923076924]
[(2, 3.3, 4), (10, 11, 12), 0.3]
[(2, 3.3, 4), (11, 12, 13), 0.27499999999999997]
[(2, 3.3, 4), (12, 13, 14), 0.25384615384615383]
```

Comment: `from multiprocessing import Pool` then use `pool.map` to split the outer loop across the process pool.

Comment: I receive "ImportError: cannot import name Pool."  Assuming I coded it poorly I tried a script with only "import multiprocessing print multiprocessing.__file__" and receive the same error.

Comment: Good news/bad news.  The good news is I got multiprocessing pool working and it's definately faster using Python.  The bad news is I run the actual application with PyPy and using multiprocessing pool with PyPy is slower than PyPy without a multiprocessing pool.  That makes little sense to me so I'll have to research it further.

Answer (score 0):

Simply switching from an explicit `for` loop to a list comprehension and using a `tuple` instead of a `list` can significantly speed up your operation:

```
from itertools import product

ResultList = [(c, d, c[1] / d[1]) for a, b in product(t1, t2) for c, d in product(a, b)]
#             ^Use a tuple here instead of a list
```

As can be shown by the `timeit` trial below:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> original_test = Timer('original_version(Tuple1, Tuple2)', '''\
... Tuple1 = (
...     ((1, 2.2, 3), (2, 3.3, 4)), 
...     ((5, 6.6, 7), (6, 7.7, 8))
... )
... Tuple2 = (
...     ((10, 11, 12), (11, 12, 13), (12, 13, 14)), 
...     ((20, 21, 22), (21, 22, 23), (22, 23, 24))
... )
... def original_version(t1, t2):
...     ResultList = []
...     for a in t1:
...         for b in t2:
...             for c in a:
...                 for d in b:
...                     ResultList.append([c, d, c[1] / d[1]])''')
>>> improved_test = Timer('improved_version(Tuple1, Tuple2)', '''\
... from itertools import product
... Tuple1 = (
...     ((1, 2.2, 3), (2, 3.3, 4)), 
...     ((5, 6.6, 7), (6, 7.7, 8))
... )
... Tuple2 = (
...     ((10, 11, 12), (11, 12, 13), (12, 13, 14)), 
...     ((20, 21, 22), (21, 22, 23), (22, 23, 24))
... )
... def improved_version(t1, t2):
...     return [(c, d, c[1] / d[1]) for a, b in product(t1, t2) for c, d in product(a, b)]''')
>>> original_time = original_test.timeit()
>>> improved_time = improved_test.timeit()
>>> print 'Improved version is %{} faster'.format(
...     (original_time - improved_time) / original_time * 100
... )
Improved version is %30.0181954314 faster
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, but your method generates different results.  The script should send four different ResultLists, each with six elements, to SomeFunction.

Your solution sends four identical ResultLists; each containing 24 elements.  I modified your solution to “ResultList = [(c, d, c[1] / d[1]) for c, d in product(a, b)]” to comply.

I used “time python script.py” with the following results:

question - 0m0.050s
answer   - 0m0.051s
modified answer - 0m0.050s

I also plugged your answer into my real-world application with no performance benefit.  But perhaps I don't understand your answer.

Comment: @user3180110: Sorry! I overlooked the last part about `ResultList` being 4 separate lists. Fixing.

Comment: No problem.  But does "fixing" mean you have a solution in mind?  I'm looking into array vectorization as a possible solution but am having little progress.  Perhaps I'll have to write this in C.

Comment: @user3180110: Sorry, I'm a bit busy and haven't been able to get to write up a reply. Here's a quick summary: You can get a small increase in efficiency by using a tuple instead of a list for `(c, d, c[1] / d[1])` but your loop is in polynomial time `O(n^3)`, I believe, so any linear improvements will get swallowed up when `n` gets very large (as in your case). While writing in C will, again, give you a mostly linear speed boost, it may be your best option.

Comment: I understand.  It looks as if hstack from the numpy module "might" work.  Hstack is basically zip for arrays.  Methinks the advantage of an array is the ability to perform the c[1]/d[1] with iteration.  That calculation is what really bogs things down.