# Processing list comprehension output element-by-element

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to transform the following into a list comprehension.

```
def list3function():
 for i in list3:
  print(i)
 input()
list1 = [[[1, 1],[1, 2]],[[1, 3],[1, 4]]]
list2 = [[[2, 2],[2, 1]],[[2, 2],[2, 1]]]
list3 = []
for a in list1:
 for b in list2:
  for c in a:
   for d in b:
    list3.append(c[1]/d[1]) 
  list3function() 
  list3 = []
```

The output is as follows:

```
0.5
1.0
1.0
2.0

0.5
1.0
1.0
2.0

1.5
3.0
2.0
4.0

1.5
3.0
2.0
4.0
```

The following works but how do I pass it to a function element-by-element?  In
the above example that's done after "for c in a:" completes.

```
list3 = [[x[1]/y[1] for x in i for y in j] for i in list1 for j in list2]
```

I don't want to create and then process the full list3 as it'd be huge.

Comment: In addition to my answer you can use `print(*list3,sep='\n')` instead of `for i in list3:print(i)` to print out lists with 1 fewer characters.

Comment: I noticed you have a very similar question [asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605674/optimizing-loop-faster-resultlist-append-c-d-c1-d1-array-map) from 2 years ago, are you still trying to solve the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm still trying to increase speed.

Comment: wow, well if you only need to use each element of list3 once it would run faster with a generator expression instead of list comprehension (round brackets instead of square) but good luck to you!

Comment: I thank you kindly for your answer and suggestion.  I will try a generator expression.

Comment: I should mention all three of your answers worked.  I did have to change "x for a" in the second and third answers to "c for a".  An understandable typo and I mention it only for someone else using the answer.

Comment: ah yes, thank you, but if you [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) please [label it appropriately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put inner two for loops in list comprehension:

```
list1= ...
list2 = ...
for a in list1:
 for b in list2:
  list3=[c[1]/d[1] for c in a for d in b]
  list3function()
```

This is probably the best way to do it although since you are clearly code golfing you could also just iterate over the expression you figured out as `list3` as the iteration variable:

```
for list3 in ([c[1]/d[1] for c in a for d in b] 
                 for a in list1 for b in list2):
  list3function()
```

which is really just a one line `for` loop:

```
for list3 in ([c[1]/d[1] for c in a for d in b] for a in list1 for b in list2):list3function()
```